# Configure Webpack 4 with aliases, Babel 7 to build React components library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to create two React projects:

- React components library (only components without working application)
- SPA application which uses created components (examples application)

I would like to achieve a folders structure like:

- `./src` - directory with React components
- `./example` - contains SPA app which uses ./src components

There are configuration files in example directory (simplest React + webpack config without HMR and other stuff):

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const aliases = require('./aliases.js');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: aliases
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

**aliases.js**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  'webpack-alias-react': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
};
```

**babel.rc**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

VSCode alias config is in `jsconfig.json` file.

And there is my problem. 
When `./src/SimpleComponent` contains code like that:

```
const SimpleComponent = () => {
  return 'string';
};
```

Running `npm run build` command builds working application.

But when `./src/SimpleComponent` returns:

```
const SimpleComponent = () => {
  return <div>abc</div>;
};
```

`npm run buid` command throws exception:

> ERROR in ../src/SimpleComponent.js Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
>   D:\Tranzystor\webpack-alias-react\src\SimpleComponent.js: Unexpected
>   token (4:9)

How to solve this webpack/Babel configuration issue?

Why is it possible to write `<div>` in `App.js`?

Is that right approach?

Whole code is [**here**](https://github.com/Tranzystor/webpack-alias-react) available.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved that issues with `Babel 7` and extended solution for that kind of issues is there:
[github](https://github.com/Tranzystor/webpack-alias-react)

It's ready to use `webpack 4 + React + Babel 7 + eslint` configuration.

It can be helpful for monorepo solutions.

Publishing your own components library to npm can be another application. As I mentioned above `./src` directory contains small react components (content which you want to publish on npm). In `./demo` directory there is spa application which shows how to use supplied components (it can be storybook for example).